# change label text in usercontrol at run time

Tags: c#

hello 
i m new to c# and im working on a project,in which i made a usercontrol1 as 
**label textbox datepicker**now i wnt to change the label text,i m trying this code but it is not working

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace library_system
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       // private string DateLabel

        public string DateLabel
        {
            **get { return DateLabel.Text; }//error when i write dateLabel.Text
            set
            {
                DateLabel.Text= value;//error datelabel.Text
            }**
        }
```

i m using this code in usercontrol for is it right to do this way??

and in the main form i m writing code as
 `userControl11.DateLabel="From Date`";//on for  load event??Is this Right
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

You are writing a property and setting itself.
If your label name is `lbl` you could simply use `lbl.Text="what you want";`
If you need a property to have a stronger check on text, you could write:

```
public string DateLabel
{
    get { return lbl.Text; }
    set { lbl.Text = value; }
}
```

So in main form you could write (suppose you have a control named uc)

```
uc.DateLabel = "hello";
```

**EDITED**
To be clear: suppose you have

- one label named `lbl` in your UserControl1 user control
- a UserControl1 control in your main form named `uc`

In your user control code you can write:

```
public string DateLabel
{
    get { return lbl.Text; }
    set { lbl.Text = value; }
}
```

In your main form you can then write:

```
uc.DateLabel = "what you want";
```

Comment: @Raghav: you have to tell us the name of the UserControl1 you placed on main form. If it is `uc` you should use `uc.DateLabel = "text";`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to this (controlname is id you have given to your label)

```
public string DateLabel
        {
            get { return controlname.Text; }
            set
            {
                controlname.Text= value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Property is Called DateLabel, and you are trying to set it. 
That doesnt make sense.

Try the following. You will need to drag a asp:Label onto you usercontrol and call it lblDateLabel.

```
public string DateLabel
{
    get { return lblDateLabel.Text; }
    set { lblDateLabel.Text= value; }
}
```